# How to add custom fields to Kentico Modules?

Tags: kentico

I want to use kentico's polls module but I need to add a "tooltip field" and add some extra HTML. Is there a way to clone the module with the same functionality and let me to edit/add fields to the module classes.

I was trying to edit the module but it shows a message saying `Classes cannot be created or deleted in installed modules.`

Answer (score 3):

Are you trying to modify the class in the module and it's giving that error? Or modify the module info itself?

Some module classes allow edits and additions. If this is not the case for the polling, you have two options.

1: clone or recreate the module and clone the web parts that use it to use your new module. This is the safest but longest task and may require some digging into Kentico drivers using a decompiler like just decompile to find any other code pieces you need to clone and modify.

2: open the database in SQL management studio, and edit the cms_class on that class and manually change the bool values that allow it to be edited. This comes with the risk that on future upgrades it may break it, but it's a small risk.

Comment: Thanks Trevor! what I did, was to copy the view and change some css classes. Then I got the title and change it to tooltip field (the labels), since I wasnt using the title field. Do you know how to get the selected answer after the Vote buttton submit??